# Mysql query with column name in spaces

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns machine id like (311a__) and (311bb__) and some of them like (08576). How can I retrieve them in SQL - how to insert into row where machine ID is like ( 311a__)? My question how to insert and select a column which has spaces in it.. How to retrieve data where machine_name ="%s__" is it correct

```
sql_local = """SELECT id FROM customer_1.pay_machines WHERE machine_name="%s" """ % machine

  retVal = cursor.execute(sql_local)
  if (retVal == 0):
    sql_local = """INSERT INTO customer_1.pay_machines (machine_name, carpark_id) VALUES ("%s", 0)""" % machine
```

Comment: select 'column name with spaces',[column name with spaces] from table_name

Comment: You should use `\`field name\``

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but your insert query is not valid sql.

Answer (score 2):

Surround odd (or [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)) column names with backticks:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM  pd 
 WHERE `machine id` = '(%s__)';
```

edit: removed invalid insert query as the first query is sufficient as an example

Comment: If you are posting code, edit it for syntax errors. `INSERT ... VALUES ... WHERE` is not valid SQL.